# For which $\alpha$ do the $\epsilon$-neighborhoods of $\{k\alpha \mod 1 \mid k = 1, \ldots , poly(1/\epsilon) \}$ cover $[0,1]$?

Tags: real-analysis, analysis, polynomials, dynamical-systems, roots

For which $\alpha$ do the $\epsilon$-neighborhoods of $\{k\alpha \mod 1 \mid k = 1, \ldots , poly(1/\epsilon) \}$ cover $[0,1]$?

In [this paper on quantum computing (last paragraph of page 25)](http://arxiv.org/abs/quantph/9812037), Dorit Aharonov claims

> ...we require that the sequence $\alpha$ mod 1, 2$\alpha$ mod 1, 3$\alpha$ mod 1, ... hits the $\epsilon$-neighborhood of any number in [0, 1], within $poly(1/\epsilon)$ steps. Clearly, $\alpha$ should be irrational, but not all irrational numbers satisfy this property. **It is not very difficult** to see that an irrational root of a polynomial of degree 2 satisfies the required property.

However, I still can't see how to see this, especially the part with roots of a quadratic polynomial.

Comment: What's $poly(1/\epsilon)$?

Comment: It's not explicitly written in the paper. I guess it means that number of steps is a polynomial in $1/\epsilon$.

Comment: So how is it obvious that $poly(1/\epsilon)$ is an integer? or does the notation really mean $\lfloor poly(1/\epsilon)\rfloor$, where $\lfloor \bullet\rfloor$ is the floor function?

Comment: @DanielRust It doesn't matter how **exactly** does $poly(1/\epsilon)$ round to integers. There just have to be **roughly** polynomial number of them, not exponential or more. In the mentioned article, $epsilon$ is a certain allowed error of approximation (see the paper, it's hard to explain it here) and $poly(1/\epsilon)$ will be the count of universal quantum gates (formally unitary matrices) for a quantum computer. Polynomial amount of these "universal elements" is a natural requirement for construction...

Comment: It may have something to do with the fact that quadratic irrationals have eventually periodic continued fraction expansion, and the Guass map $h\colon x\mapsto \frac{1}{x}-\lfloor \frac{1}{x}\rfloor$, which acts on continued fractions by $h([0;a_0,a_1,a_2\ldots])=[0;a_1,a_2,a_3,\ldots]$, has all quadratic irrationals in $[0,1]$ as eventually periodic points.

Comment: I'm not able to really understand that - is that the whole proof or just a hint to which direction we should go? And is there taken into account the polynomial count of hits?

Comment: Sorry, I just offered that result as a possible method of attack as I'm not sure of how to solve the question myself (I'm still a little unsure of what the question is asking but I think I have a rough idea now). Good luck solving it, and I'll be sure to post an answer if I do ever find a solution myself.